# Calling React js Fetch Calls In a Sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, fetch-api

Someone, please help me to call these fetch API's one after the other as I am using the data which is stored in the backend for my next request. I want them to be called sequentially one complete then next request this way.

```
 Promise.all([
   fetch(`http://localhost:5000/zoomapi`, 
    requestOptions),

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/getId')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ zoomid: result });      
    }),

   fetch(`http://localhost:5000/users/zoom?name=${this.state.zoomid}`)
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then((result) => {
       this.setState({ zoomdata: result });
      })  
  ])
   .catch((error) => {
       this.setState({ error });
   });


  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.setState` is not a synchronous operation, so you cannot use `const id = this.state.zoomid`, you can use `result` instead. In addition, your promises should be chained, not nested. Example:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5000/getId')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ zoomid: result });
        return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/users/zoom?name=${result}`);
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ zoomdata: result });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ error });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear with my question. But I am calling a fetch before the above two fetches in which I update the variable in node backend and when I get using '/getId' I want the updated Variable id which i still get the old temporary one. So please help with that.  And thank you for the promise suggestion, I have made the changes instead of nesting.